# jQuery Onclick event on specific h2 containing specific text

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div that has been included into my page dynamicly so I don't have access to it as it's not on my current page.

This is how it looks:

```
<h2 class="title">About</h2>
```

What I need to do is to add an 'onclick' event that targets this div.

All I know is that it's a 'h2' with a class of 'title' and with text containing 'About'.

How can I do this?

Comment: `$(document).on('click','h2.title', function(){     //YOUR CODE });`

Comment: hi! Something like $(document).on('click','.title',function(event){}); ? (or maybe change .title to h2.title...) What did you try actually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use :contains to select also contained text like this:

```
$("h2.title:contains('About')").click(function(e) {
    // Handle here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
$(document).on('click','h2.title', function(e){ 
    if(e.currentTarget.textContent.trim() == "About") {
    //write your code here
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.filter` for specific match. 
As `:contains` will match `<h2 class="title">About Us</h2>` as well.

```
$("h2.title").filter(function () {
    return $.trim($(this).text()) == "About";
}).click(function(e) {

});
```